# Using php variable in jQuery Script

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to get this code to work but cannot figure out how to make it work correctly. I think I am close though. This code works fine on my page:

```
var entryID = $(this).attr('id');

    if ("<?php echo $locations[2]['floor']; ?>" == 'firstFloor' ) {
        $("#drawTable").attr("style", "background:url(\'images/firstFloor.jpg\') 50% / 100% no-repeat;");
    }
    else if ("<?php echo $locations[2]['floor']; ?>" == 'secondFloor' ) {
        $("#drawTable").attr("style", "background:url(\'images/secondFloor.jpg\') 50% / 100% no-repeat;");
    }
```

I am trying to make the array changeable by using the entryID instead of just a number like '2'. I do not think that I am concatenating correctly below. If you can help It would be much appreciated! Thank you

```
var entryID = $(this).attr('id');

    if ("<?php echo $locations . "[";?>" +entryID+ "<?php echo "]['floor']"; ?>" == 'firstFloor' ) {
        $("#drawTable").attr("style", "background:url(\'images/firstFloor.jpg\') 50% / 100% no-repeat;");
    }
    else if ("<?php echo $locations . "[";?>" +entryID+ "<?php echo "]['floor']"; ?>" == 'secondFloor' ) {
        $("#drawTable").attr("style", "background:url(\'images/secondFloor.jpg\') 50% / 100% no-repeat;");
    }
```

Comment: add related HTML tag

Comment: You cant access php array through javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then thing is you can't do that as PHP already ran on server and javascript has started to work way later after DOM ready. So, that is not possible such way. Instead you can store<sup>1</sup> the array in a js variable like:

```js
var entryID = $(this).attr('id');
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations); ?>; // i suppose this could be array.
var floor = locations[entryID]['floor']; // <----target the floor here

if (floor === 'firstFloor') {
  $("#drawTable").css("background", "('images/firstFloor.jpg') 50% 100% no-repeat;");
} else if (floor === 'secondFloor') {
  $("#drawTable").css("background", "url('images/secondFloor.jpg') 50% 100% no-repeat;");
}
```

and Instead of `attr` such way better to use `css` or event better `addClass`.

<sup>*1. - The js has to be written on php page.*</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked like a charm! I very much appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You cant access php array through javascript. for this you should convert php array to javascript array and assign it in javascript variable after that you can access that array. Like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Assign php generated json to JavaScript variable
    var tempArray = <?php echo json_encode($locations); ?>;

   //You will be able to access the properties as 
    alert(tempArray[0].Key);
</script>
```